# Bash script read specifc value from files of an entire folder

Tags: bash, awk

I have a problem creating a script that reads specific value from all the files of an entire folder

I have a number of email files in a directory and I need to extract from each file, 2 specific values.

After that I have to put them into a new file that looks like that:

```
--------------
To: value1

value2
--------------
```

This is what I want to do, but I don't know how to create the script:

```
# I am putting the name of the files into a temp file
`ls -l | awk '{print $9 }' >tmpfile` 

# use for the name of a file
`date=`date +"%T" 

# The first specific value from file (phone number)
var1=`cat tmpfile | grep "To: 0" | awk '{print $2 }' | cut -b -10 `

# The second specific value from file(subject)
var2=cat file | grep Subject | awk '{print $2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9$10 }'

# Put the first value in a new file on the first row
echo "To: 4"$var1""  > sms-$date

# Put the second value in the same file on the second row
echo ""$var2"" >>sms-$date 

.......
```

and do the same for every file in the directory

I tried using while and for functions but I couldn't finalize the script

Thank You

Comment: There probably more than one mistake, but first is that `tmpfile` contains list of file names and when you do `cat tmpfile | grep "To: 0"` you search in the file names and not in file contents, as you suppose.

Comment: No need for tmpfile at all, just do `grep -h "To: 0" *`.

Comment: Another one: `var2=cat file | grep Subject | awk '{print $2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9$10 }'` there backticks are absent. Also I don't understand what inside the `file` file?

Comment: i wanted to write tmpfile instead of file

Comment: imho, you should to start with the next command: 
`egrep  -H "^(To|Subject): " *` and process the output lines.

Comment: Can you add a sample input file to the question please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a few changes to your script, hopefully they will be useful to you:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *; do
    var1=$(awk '/To: 0/ {print substr($2,0,10)}' "$file")
    var2=$(awk '/Subject/ {for (i=2; i<=10; ++i) s=s$i; print s}' "$file")    
    outfile="sms-"$(date +"%T")
    i=0
    while [ -f "$outfile" ]; do outfile="sms-$date-"$((i++)); done
    echo "To: 4$var1" > "$outfile"
    echo "$var2" >> "$outfile"
done
```

- The `for` loop just goes through every file in the folder that you run the script from.
- I have added added an additional suffix `$i` to the end of the file name. If no file with the same date already exists, then the file will be created without the suffix. Otherwise the value of `$i` will keep increasing until there is no file with the same name.
- I'm using `$( )` rather than backticks, this is just a personal preference but it can be clearer in my opinion, especially when there are other quotes about.
- There's not usually any need to pipe the output of `grep` to `awk`. You can do the search in `awk` using the `/  /` syntax.
- I have removed the `cut -b -10` and replaced it with `substr($2, 0, 10)`, which prints the first 10 characters from column 2.
- It's not much shorter but I used a loop rather than the `$2$3...`, I think it looks a bit neater.
- There's no need for all the extra `"` in the two output lines.

Answer (score 0):

I sugest to try the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

RESULT_FILE=sms-`date +"%T"`
DIR=.

fgrep -l 'To: 0' "$DIR" | while read FILE; do
    var1=`fgrep 'To: 0' "$FILE" | awk '{print $2 }' | cut -b -10`
    var2=`fgrep 'Subject' "$FILE" | awk '{print $2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9$10 }'`

    echo "To: 4$var1" >>"$RESULT_FIL"
    echo "$var2" >>"$RESULT_FIL"
done
```

Comment: it does not work...it doesn't do anything...it halts

Comment: @user3472214 oops, I'm sorry. Fixed it now. By default it do search within current directory, but you may specify another one by changing `DIR` variable.